# POST and PUT requests in angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to create a reusable service so that I can add, update, delete etc using the following code:

The get works however I get an error with the other functions? why is that

```
app.factory('requestService',['$http', function ($http) {
// reusable get request
return {
    getRequest: function (url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
};   
return {
    postRequest :function (url, data) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        url: url
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        return response;
    });
}
}
// reusable put request
return {
    putRequest: function (url, data) {
        return $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            data: data,
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
};
// reusable delete request
return {
deleteRequest: function (url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
};
```

The get works when i pass in a url however when i pass data into the post and put functions i get the error requestService.postRequest is not a function.

I have the called the function in another controller by defining it correctly but when calling the post it just returns the error.

```
app.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http, requestService) {
```

I have called the post function by doing the following:

```
requestService.postRequest('https://.....',{key:value}).then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: You have to return it too like you did for the other functions: return {
    postRequest: function (url, data) { }}

Comment: @Mils even with the edit i get the same error

Comment: When there are several return statements in a code block, only the first one is executed. Subsquent return statements are skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put the fuctions inside the first return, like this:

```
app.factory('requestService',['$http', function ($http) {
return {
    getRequest: function (url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    },
    postRequest : function(url, data) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    },
    putRequest: function (url, data) {
        return $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            data: data,
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    },
    deleteRequest: function (url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The code needs to re-throw from the error handlers. When an error handler returns a value, it converts a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise.

Comment: I now get an error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, referencing the requestService.postRequest('https://.....',{key:value}).then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
    });

Comment: @William.Doyle You may not be returning a value from your factory which is cause you to see the "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error.  If nothing is returned it will throw that error.